# How can we check if a domain is valid or not in go?

Tags: go

How can we check if a domain is valid or not in go? Is there some function in go to validate it?
Some of the conditions are

1.) The domain length should be between 4 and 48

2.) Domain should use only letters, numbers, hyphens, and periods.

Example

something.in -> valid

some-stuff.in -> valid

some!thing.com -> invalid

Comment: @CeriseLimón That one is a bit too simple. Each label can be up 63 charaters. Dashes at start/end of labels are complicated, the max length of a domain is 253, IDNs are not handled, labels of len 0 are disallowed, etc. While your regexp handles what the OP asked for it is not what the OP probably needs (even if he doesn't know).

Comment: Are you asking what the rules are for a valid domain name? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#RFC_documents: "The definitive descriptions of the rules for forming domain names appear in RFC 1035, RFC 1123, RFC 2181, and RFC 5892.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the net package? : https://golang.org/pkg/net/?m=all#isDomainName and maybe also combining it with checking the length with len() ?

Comment: That link no longer works; would you be able to update your answer with the context that used to be there?